# clover and its coverage report without writing test cases

Tags: clover

i am totally new to clover and its coverage...

i have a web-application in java and i attached clover through ant,and eclipse and successfully i have written test cases for classes and it generating report as test passed.

but in both cases it generates report once at the time run project with clover and to cover all code i need to write test cases for all classes.

My requirements is that i want to attach clover with my application and after run on server if i clicked links from browser then it generate the report how much code covered internally and also it should be increase with more links execution....

i don't know is it possible or not...??

if is it possible please give me some ideas.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a single coverage report containing coverage from both unit tests and a manual execution of an application.

I think these articles might help you:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Clover+in+various+environment+configurations
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Clover+for+web+applications